# SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE between 2 numbers in column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count how many records I have in my column 'routeorder' that are between 2 numbers. The column has information like:

```
RouteOrder
ACC-001-01
ACC-001-01
ACC-001-01
ACC-001-01
ACC-015-18
ACC-015-18
ACC-015-18
ACC-015-18
ACC-015-19
ACC-015-19
ACC-015-19
ACC-015-19
ACC-015-19
ACC-016-01
ACC-016-01
ACC-016-01
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
ACC-017-19
```

I need to get how many records between 'ACC-001' and 'ACC-016'
Is there a way to do it ?
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as areatotals FROM Customers WHERE SUBSTRING(routeorder,LENGTH(routeorder),-3) like 'ACC'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what does your table structure look like? do you have a primary key in it ?

Answer (score 2):

Going from the example given on the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), you should be able to that:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as areatotals FROM Customers WHERE routeorder BETWEEN 'ACC-001' AND 'ACC-016';`

This should trigger a string conversion as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: This was going to be my answer, here is [a SQLfiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7251/2).

Comment: wow... cannot believe it can be done that easily !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT count(*) counts,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(RouteOrder , 5),1,3 ) as str 
FROM Customers
GROUP BY str
HAVING str > 001 and str < 016
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02994/26)

output:

```
   COUNTS   STR
    9       015
```

**EDIT:**

here more simpler and fits your needs if the first part is changing.

```
 SELECT count(*) counts,SUBSTRING(RouteOrder ,-6 ,3) as str 
 FROM Customers
 GROUP BY str
 HAVING str > 001 and str < 016
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b70ef/2)

Comment: Thanks for this... I am playing with demo now. What happens if the first part of the routeorder is only 2 characters or its 4 or 5 characters long ?

Comment: only the first part who is changing ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need to substring or typecast anything. the `BETWEEN` Operator is also working for strings: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE RouteOrder BETWEEN "ACC-002" AND "ACC-007"`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9614c/1

And if you want to include the Upperbound matches also, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE RouteOrder BETWEEN "ACC-002" AND "ACC-007" OR RouteOrder LIKE "ACC-007%"`

(the `like` you need, because when comparing strings `ACC-007-1` is technically NOT smaller or equal to `ACC-007`, which means, the between operator will exclude that)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9614c/2